# Arduino compiler: preprocessor definitions not sourced from boards.txt in docker container

Tags: docker, arduino

I'm attempting to compile a program with the CLI via docker, but I'm getting errors because it isn't populating the preprocessor definitions from boards.txt.

The specific error is a byproduct of that, but in case someone is searching for it later, the error is: `USB_VID was not declared in this scope` from `cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp`

I see the following when running the exact same command in and out of docker, note all the definitions from boards.txt when outside of docker.

(Only the first command is shown and line breaks added for clarity)

**In docker**

```
FQBN: adafruit:avr:itsybitsy32u4_5V                                                                                                                                                                                
Using board 'itsybitsy32u4_5V' from platform in folder: /arduino/data/packages/adafruit/hardware/avr/1.4.15                                                                                                        
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /arduino/data/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Detecting libraries used...                                                                                                                                                                                        
/arduino/data/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++ 
-c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions 
-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics 
-Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega32u4 
-DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 
-DARDUINO_AVR_ITSYBITSY32U4_5V -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR 
-I/arduino/data/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/
arduino -I/arduino/data/packages/adafruit/hardware/avr/1.4.15/variants/itsybitsy32u4 /tmp/arduino/sketches/25FEAC7B78438B08E47BECDAC46A201D/sketch/itsy-serial.ino.cpp 
-o /dev/null
```

**Out of docker**

```
FQBN: adafruit:avr:itsybitsy32u4_5V
Using board 'itsybitsy32u4_5V' from platform in folder: /home/foobar/.arduino15/packages/adafruit/hardware/avr/1.4.15
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /home/foobar/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6

Detecting libraries used...
/home/foobar/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++ 
-c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions 
-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics 
-Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega32u4 
-DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 
-DARDUINO_AVR_ITSYBITSY32U4_5V -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR 
-DUSB_VID=0x239A -DUSB_PID=0x800E 
-DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Adafruit" 
-DUSB_PRODUCT="ItsyBitsy 32u4 5V 16MHz" 
-I/home/foobar/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino 
-I/home/foobar/.arduino15/packages/adafruit/hardware/avr/1.4.15/variants/itsybitsy32u4 /tmp/arduino/sketches/5DD7AD486AC39BA7E1BDA250FDC110C8/sketch/itsy-serial.ino.cpp 
-o /dev/null
```

I tried checking the source code to see if I'm missing an env variable or something of the like, but I'm not fluent in go and it's tough to trace the chain of execution.

Anyone have any suggestions?

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy

ENV ARDUINO_DIRECTORIES_USER=/arduino/user
ENV ARDUINO_DIRECTORIES_DOWNLOADS=/arduino/staging
ENV ARDUINO_DIRECTORIES_DATA=/arduino/data
ENV ARDUINO_BOARD_MANAGER_ADDITIONAL_URLS=https://adafruit.github.io/arduino-board-index/package_adafruit_index.json

ENV PATH=/arduino/bin:$PATH

RUN apt update && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
      curl \
      ca-certificates && \
    mkdir -p /arduino/bin /arduino/data /arduino/staging /arduino/user && \
    export BINDIR=/arduino/bin && \
    curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arduino/arduino-cli/master/install.sh | sh && \
    ln -s /arduino/bin/arduino-cli /arduino/bin/acli && \
    acli core update-index && \
    acli core install arduino:avr && \
    acli core install adafruit:avr
```